# \ Mvc \ User \ Plugin not found

Tags: php, phalcon

I need to update from PHP 7.3 to PHP 8.0 or PHP 8.1.

About composer.json php from ~ 7.3.0 to ^ 8.0, ext-phalcon from ^ 3.3.0 to 5.0.0 beta3 I think I have to update to

It changed as follows

I was using the following on my existing system:
use Phalcon\Mvc\User\Plugin;

I couldn't find it, and when I checked git, it was written as follows.
https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/blob/f1315049b46c0e3d348c6446e592c071b901f011/resources/CHANGELOG-4.0.md
Changed Phalcon\Mvc\User\Plugin to Phalcon\Plugin
Removed Phalcon\Mvc\User\Component, Phalcon\Mvc\User\Module and Phalcon\Mvc\User\Plugin

I searched for Phalcon \ Plugin but can't find it.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\Phalcon\Di\Injectable` namespace instead.

Comment: thank you very much. Thanks to you, I solved it.